# Tensorprodukt definition through universal arrow/Comma category

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

i am a beginner in category theory.
I like the CoLimit/Limit definition through universal arrows but i am still confused how to relate that thought with the tensor-product definition.

In CWM i found a example of the tensor-product for rings defined through the use of the colimit definition through  universal arrows and i wanted to ask if you could give me the example of the tensor-product R-module definition through universal arrows or the reason why this is not working...

Comment: What's CWM, by the way?

Comment: Categories for the Working Mathematician